# How to correct this Slax Module Manager issue?

Tags: linux, slax

I was testing some modules for Slax - some Gparted modules and some requirements for it - adding and removing them.

But when I restarted OS, Slax Module Manager did not work anymore. When I try to install another module, a pop-up displays a message telling an error occurred in installation with no technical details.

When I put some modules in modules folder, they are installed but only after rebooting, but I'd like to test more modules installing and uninstalling them without restarting.

Is there any way to correct that issue in Module Manager without reinstalling Slax?

Comment: Have you tried just restarting the module manager and slax?

Comment: So it shows up 'live' then disappears when you restart? Can you clarify "restarted OS Slax Module Manager" Do you mean when you restarted the OS? or the Slax Manager?

Comment: yeah. i'll put more punctuation marks :) "But when I restarted OS Slax Module Manager..." => "But when I restarted OS, Slax Module Manager..."

Comment: Apologies. Is this what happens? You install the package, and dont see it until you restart the OS?

Comment: well, i'll try to be more clear: i installed 10 modules and then i uninstalled 9 modules. after that i turned off computer. some hours later, i turned on again and slax starts normally. when i try to install another module, i could not and a popup appears with a message saying that there were an error installing that module. i downloaded more modules, but i cannot install them too. i turned of/on computer some times but i cannot install modules anymore :( i saw later that copying modules to modules folder make them installed, but doing so i have to turn off and then on the computer...

Comment: So its a generic, you can't install modules?

Comment: yeah. i can't install any modules using the common way: clicking twice in downloaded module. i think it's an error in Module Manager. i can make modules function if i copy modules to modules folder and then turning off and turning on computer. i would like to fix module manager issue. :)

Comment: i dont know why someone downvoted. please, comment your reasons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find one solution, not the best one, but it avoids that kind of problem.

### Solution

Add Slax modules saving them (the .LZM files) to /slax/modules folder.

### Description

When booting/rebooting Slax, .LZM files on /slax/modules folder are loaded as they were installed by clicking twice on it inside OS.

### Advantage

When operational system is "broken" (i.e., when it does not boot anymore or some "crazy" problems occurs in its use, like that reported error in Slax Module Manager), you can just delete /slax/changes folder and maintain your modules in /slax/modules folder. You will lost some SO customizations, but you will maintain your custom programs.